# How can I view EBCDIC formatted files in VIM?

Tags: vim

What is the best way to view an [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) formatted file in VIM?

Comment: Does `:echo has("ebcdic")` return `0` or `1`?

Comment: @romainl it returns 0

Comment: Most Vim binaries today come without `ebcdic` support (just tested it on a couple of distros).  You can check it by executing `has("ebcdic")` as romainl suggests or by running `vim --version` and searching for `+ebcdic`/`-ebcdic` (supported/not supported).  You might ned to compile Vim to get `ebcdic` support.  Yet, today most `ebcdic` is used in ancient communications (e.g. chipcards and ATM) that once ran on mainframes.  Do you really need to see `ebcdic` or would seeing hex bytes (like `xxd <file>`) be enough?  (also, we have [vi.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com) for vim questions)

Comment: @grochmal - thank you. unfortunately hex bytes won't be enough, even though it is ancient and i'd rather not deal with it, i'd like to pull in ebcdic support.
if you put your comment as an answer, i'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Wait, I was **completely** wrong.  I went to the Vim code searching how to enable `ebcdic` and discovered that `+ebcidic`/`-ebcdic` mean something completely different.  To support `ebcidic` Vim actually needs the `+iconv` feature instead.  I will add an answer shortly (as soon as I test this).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### On a mainframe

First of all, if Vim was compiled and is running on a system which default encoding is EDCDIC (e.g. an IBM manframe with an ANSI C compiler) then Vim will open EBCDIC files in the system's code page by default.  Such an instance of Vim will have:

```
has("ebcdic")
```

evaluating to `1`.  And when invoked with `--version` Vim will print:

```
+ebcdic
```

Instances of Vim not compiled in an EBCDIC environment will never evaluate `has("ebcdic")` to true.  This feature of Vim is needed because other features behave differently in a purely EBCDIC environment.

---

#### Not on a mainframe

Yet, most systems today do not use EBCDIC code pages.  For the situation where a file encoded in an EBCDIC code page needs to be edited in Vim on a more popular system, Vim uses the `iconv` library.  In essence, to be able to open a file encoded in an EBCDIC code page Vim needs to be compiled with `iconv` support.  `iconv` support can be tested by evaluating:

```
has("iconv")
```

Or searching for the

```
+iconv
```

string in the output of `vim --version`.

EBCDIC has several code pages, and Vim will only be capable of using the code pages supported by the `iconv` library it was compiled against.  To check which code pages are available you can use the `iconv` utility that comes together with the `iconv` library:

```
iconv --list
```

Now, let's assume that we have a file called `myfile` encoded with the  `EBCDIC-US` code page (also called the `EBCDIC-037` code page) and that the `iconv` installed on the system supports this code page.

Before opening the file in Vim we need to set Vim's encoding to `utf-8`, in `~/.vimrc` we need:

```
set enc=utf-8
```

`:h fenc` advises that the encoding must be set to `utf-8` if any file conversion (through `iconv`) is performed.  Otherwise data loss is possible when writing the file back.

Now we open the file in Vim with `vim myfile` and see mangled characters.  That is fine, we now need to perform the conversion using `iconv` with:

```
:e ++enc=EBCDIC-US
```

Vim will now display the file in `utf-8` but will save the file in `EBCDIC-US`, both accomplished using `iconv` conversions on the fly.

---

#### Closing notes

The mapping between IBM's naming of code pages:

```
EBCDIC-037
EBCDIC-273
EBCDIC-500
...
```

and `iconv`'s names

```
EBCDIC-US
EBCDIC-AT-DE-A
EBCDIC-BE
...
```

Is often non-trivial.  Yet, if the display encoding (`enc`) is set to `utf-8` there should be no issue in trying different code pages with

```
:e ++enc=EBCDIC-US
:e ++enc=EBCDIC-AT-DE-A
```

until the correct conversion is found.

---

Extra note: consider using [vi.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com) if you have more questions related to Vim.

Comment: so there's no way to compile vim with both ascii and ebcdic support?

Comment: @AlexejMagura - By the contrary.  If you have `incov` compiled in you do not only have EBCDIC support but every encoding your `iconv` supports (e.g. all the CJK encodings).  Yet, your statement is true for a mainframe.  On a mainframe you can get either ASCII or the EBCDIC page of the mainframe.  (I never saw a mainframe that could compile `iconv`)

Comment: I still don't understand why the EBCDIC encodings don't work in vim just like any other encoding.

Comment: @gsl iconv usage is the main encoding library in vim, i.e. the most common processing of encodings in vim is through iconv.  The other options are for smaller builds that do not require much resources.